# Issue when adding a date to HttpParams

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a Http get request to an API, based on a certain date. Therefore I've tried to add a HttpParam, but the resulting parameter string is not looking like it's supposed to.

```
getMethod(myDate: Date): Oberservable<myObject[]>{
  console.log(myDate.toDateString())
  let params = new HttpParams()
  .set('selectedDate', myDate.toDateString()
  console.log(params.toString())

  // return statement here
}
```

The first log prints: "Tue Dec 12 2017"
The second log prints: "selectedDate=Tue%20Dec%2012%202017"

To me it looks like there's something going wrong when setting the param, but I do not now what.. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%20 represents a space in "URL language".

This means your date to string is

```
Tue Dec 12 2017
```

What is the expected format in your endpoint ?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `decodeURI()` to decode the parameter.
Then if you do `console.log(decodeURI(params.toString()))` you will get result as expected.